# Get multiple minimal number from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script for get three values (minimal numbers) from array :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var _array = [1,2,3,4];
    var save = 0;
    var _new_array = [];
    var nearDistance = [];
    $.each(new Array(3),function(n){
        if (_new_array.length < 1){
            save = Math.min.apply(Math,_array);
            _new_array = jQuery.grep(_array, function(value) {
              return value != save;
            });
            nearDistance.push(save);
        } else {
            save = Math.min.apply(Math,_new_array);
            _new_array = jQuery.grep(_new_array, function(value) {
              return value != save;
            });
            nearDistance.push(save);
        }
    });
    console.log(nearDistance);    
});
```

This script works to get 3 minimal values,

scenario script : Do each 3 times, first each get minimal value (`save`) from first array (`_array`), delete minimal value from the first array (`_array`) and then put resudial values to new array (`_new_array`), minimal value push to `nearDistance`, next each get minimal value from new array.

I think my script too less performance if I want to get more values from an array, what do you think about my script?

Comment: Please don't invalidate answers by editing the code.

Comment: @EthanBierlein sorry my bad, I didn't edit the code but simplify the code from joseph suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to:

- Get n smallest numbers from your array.
- The original array doesn't get mutated.

First off:

- Underscores have a special meaning in programming. They're used to denote pseudo-private variables. Since JS has no concept of private (unless emulated with closures), prefixing an underscore to a publicly accessible variable means not to access that variable directly.
- For this operation, you don't need jQuery. Vanilla JS has it's own [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for `$.each` and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for `$.grep`.
- Just so you know, `$` and `jQuery` are the same. The `$` is an alias made for convenience. `jQuery` is the global of jQuery to prevent issue with clobbering. IIRC, MooTools uses the `$` global. Anyone can alias their library as `$`, but who names their library "jQuery" besides jQuery?
- `$(document).ready(fn)` can be shortened to `$(fn)` or `jQuery(fn)`.
- This operation is best moved out to a function so that you can call this out, pass in an array, and get the results you want.
- Another problem is that `$.grep` return a new array every call. That means on each iteration of `$.each`, you're creating a new array - which is bad.
- `Math.min` in your code will always return the smallest number. This means on every push, the numbers run from smallest to largest. Why not sort the array first and slice the first `n`?

Running with the above assumptions and review, you can do this:

```js
function getSmallestNumbers(array, n) {
  // We slice first to prevent mutation of the original array when we
  // do `sort`. Then we slice again to get n items.
  return array.slice().sort().slice(0, n);
}

var distances = [4, 3, 1, 2];
var nearDistances = getSmallestNumbers(distances, 3);

// SE should seriously have a console view
document.write(JSON.stringify(nearDistances));
```

Comment: Good catch about the 'original array doesn't get mutated'. Slice fixes this :)

Comment: Nice!, thanks @joseph for some suggestion about syntax, I have try your solution but why still get wrong number If an array have some number like `[22.4, 1.1, 102.14, 89.5]`, I think that sort every character of value not per value, sound like sort with ascending A to Z

Comment: @itx You can provide a sort with a custom sorting function. indofraiser's answer has that detail.

Answer (score 1):

> what do you think about my script?

You really want to know what I think? Cause it aint pretty...

I don't mind reading bad english, because not everyone is a native speaker. But that's not the problem here. `nearDistance`, `_newArray`, `save`, ... are just really bad variable names. They tell me nothing.

I mean, whats it with that underscore? Where are the comments explaining what and why? Why are you doing a `$.each(new Array())` instead of a simple for loop? Why are you defining variables outside of the scope they are used in?

I think you ran into a couple of meta-problems here. So let's take a step back!

## Work smarter not harder

I'm still not sure what exactly your code should do, but doesn't this also work?

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];
var newArray = myArray.sort().slice(0,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

First comment echos @Pinoniq tidy up your variable names. Instantly it will look cleaner.

Second, you are repeating the same save code, so move it into a later block. Better yet, class it from a separate class.

You should also determine if you need to have so much code for `firstArray` when you do not need to change it.

I've done this in Notepad so it's not checked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var firstArray = [1,2,3,4];
    var answer = 0;
    var newArray = [];
    var nearDistance = [];

    $.each(newArray (3),function(n){
        if (newArray .length < 1){
            answer = Math.min.apply(firstArray );
            newArray  = jQuery.grep(firstArray , function(value) {
        } else {
            answer = Math.min.apply(Math,newArray ); 
            newArray  = jQuery.grep(newArray  , function(value) {

        }    
               return value != answer
            });
            nearDistance.push(answer);
    });
    console.log(nearDistance);    
});
```

You should really look at:

```
var _array = [1,3,2];
Math.max.apply(Math,_array); // 3
Math.min.apply(Math,_array); // 1
```

on [this feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985341/get-max-and-min-value-from-array-in-javascript) and I would strongly suggest looking at [this link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml).

An example:

```
 function sortfunction(a, b){
     return (a - b) //causes an array to be sorted numerically and ascending
     }
```